# How to make executor reject new tasks when another is running?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Using this executor

```
executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

Will run only one task at once, but will execute any subsequent tasks  in sequence.
I want it to reject new tasks if it is already running one.
Should i use another type of executor? Which one? Or should i look for a different approach here?

Comment: What's the big picture? You want to drop any tasks that can't be executed immediately?

Comment: exactly, throw an exception or just reject the task

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with core and maximum pool size of `1`.

Finally you need to provide a [SynchronousQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/SynchronousQueue.html) as the queue (although it's not really a queue at all), to make sure that a task is executed only if the single thread is available, otherwise a `RejectedExecutionException` is thrown.

As a one-liner (the timeout is not applicable in this use case):

```
new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>());
```

See the other constructors if you wish to handle the rejected tasks in some special way. Especially [DiscardPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy.html) if you don't want even an exception from the rejected tasks.

This also scales up to more than one thread just by increasing the pool sizes. If corepool is less than maxpool, the timeout will again be relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Code snippet:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor= new ThreadPoolExecutor(1,1,
                    60,TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1),
                    new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
```

Refer to this post about different discard policies:

[Using ThreadPoolExecutor and DiscardPolicy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299784/using-threadpoolexecutor-and-discardpolicy/35691415#35691415)

Comment: Does not achieve what is requested. This code allows for the queueing of one task while another is running.

Comment: It queues 1 task. But further tasks are rejected

Comment: Yes, and that's 1 task too much. He wants to queue 0 tasks, and execute 1 at a time.