# Handle back-pressure in FixedThreadPool

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, java.util.concurrent, backpressure

## How to deal with back-pressure in Java using thread pool?

How to reject new tasks so there are no more than **N** submitted tasks. **N** - is the maximum number of allowed tasks in submission queue, which include new, running, paused (not finished) tasks.

### Use case

Users submit calculation tasks that **run for some time**. Sometimes, there are so many users submitting tasks at the same time. How to reject new tasks if there are already **N** tasks submitted.

In other words, the **total number of submitted** (not finished, started or not started) tasks cannot be greater than **N**.

### Example code

[Here is full version](https://github.com/yan-khonski-it/back-pressure-example) and bellow are short snippets.

A long running task. **CalculationTask**.

```
public class CalculationTask {
    public CalculationTask(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public CalculationResult calculate() {
        final long waitTimeMs = MIN_WAIT_TIME_MS + RANDOM.nextInt(MAX_WAIT_TIME_MS);
        sleep(waitTimeMs);
        final int result = Math.abs(RANDOM.nextInt());
        final String text = "This is result: " + result;
        final CalculationResult calculationResult = new CalculationResult(name, text, result);
        System.out.println("Calculation finished: " + calculationResult);
        return calculationResult;
    }
}
```

Its result. **CalculationResult**.

```
public class CalculationResult {

    private final String taskName;
    private final String text;
    private final Integer number;
    // Getters, setters, constructor, toString.
}
```

This is how I submit jobs. **CalculationBroker**.

```
public class CalculationBroker {

    private static final int MAX_WORKERS_NUMBER = 5;

    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_WORKERS_NUMBER);
    private final Map<String, CalculationResult> calculationCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public CompletableFuture<CalculationResult> submit(final CalculationTask calculationTask) {
        final CalculationResult calculationResultCached = calculationCache.get(calculationTask.getName());
        if (calculationResultCached != null) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(calculationResultCached);
        }

        System.out.println("Calculation submitted: " + calculationTask.getName());

        final CompletableFuture<CalculationResult> calculated = CompletableFuture
                .supplyAsync(calculationTask::calculate, executorService);
        calculated.thenAccept(this::updateCache);
        return calculated;
    }

    private void updateCache(final CalculationResult calculationResult) {
        calculationCache.put(calculationResult.getTaskName(), calculationResult);
    }
}
```

And this is how I run them together. **Main**.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int N_TASKS = 100;
        final CalculationBroker calculationBroker = new CalculationBroker();
        final List<CompletableFuture<CalculationResult>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < N_TASKS; i++) {
            final CalculationTask calculationTask = createCalculationTask(i);
            final CompletableFuture<CalculationResult> calculationResultCompletableFuture =
                    calculationBroker.submit(calculationTask);
            completableFutures.add(calculationResultCompletableFuture);
        }

        calculationBroker.close();
    }

    private static CalculationTask createCalculationTask(final int counter) {
        return new CalculationTask("CalculationTask_" + counter);
    }
}
```

This is output.

```
2020-05-23 14:14:53 [main] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationBroker – Calculation submitted: CalculationTask_97.
2020-05-23 14:14:53 [main] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationBroker – Calculation submitted: CalculationTask_98.
2020-05-23 14:14:53 [main] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationBroker – Calculation submitted: CalculationTask_99.
2020-05-23 14:14:54 [pool-1-thread-3] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationTask – Calculation finished: CalculationResult{taskName='CalculationTask_2', text='This is result: 1081871544', number=1081871544, durationMs=1066}
2020-05-23 14:14:55 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationTask – Calculation finished: CalculationResult{taskName='CalculationTask_0', text='This is result: 1942553785', number=1942553785, durationMs=1885}
2020-05-23 14:14:56 [pool-1-thread-5] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationTask – Calculation finished: CalculationResult{taskName='CalculationTask_4', text='This is result: 104326011', number=104326011, durationMs=2120}
20
```

## My findings.

[Bellow details](https://www.nurkiewicz.com/2014/11/executorservice-10-tips-and-tricks.html)

> Code above is equivalent to Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n), however instead of default unlimited LinkedBlockingQueue we use ArrayBlockingQueue with fixed capacity of 100. This means that if 100 tasks are already queued (and n being executed), new task will be rejected with RejectedExecutionException.

`ThreadPoolExecutor` uses a `LinkedBlockingQueue`, which is unlimited by default.

As the post above sugessts:

```
final BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100);
executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(n, n, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue);
```

Comment: Just to make things clear .. you don't want to be able to submit or you want your threads to avoid start processing the new submitted calculations until you have free thread ??
_N.B: Both are possible to achieve just to be able to provide the right solution._

Comment: Good point, thanks, I updated  my question. I want to reject new tasks, so total number of submitted tasks (in the queue under the hood) is less or equal than **N**.

Comment: to employ backpressure, use reactive streams protocol.

Comment: It would be nice to see an example, @AlexeiKaigorodov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered your own question ... you could use `Queue` size to do that..

```
int poolSize = ...;
int queueSize = ...;
CustomRejectedExecutionHandler handler = new CustomRejectedExecutionHandler();

ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(poolSize, poolSize,
    0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
    new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(queueSize),
    handler);
```

You could use `CustomRejectedExecutionHandler` to handle rejected threads.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class CustomRejectedExecutionHandler implements RejectedExecutionHandler {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(CustomRejectedExecutionHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void rejectedExecution(Runnable runnable, ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor) {
        LOGGER.error(runnable.toString() + " execution rejected.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense. I did not see `RejectedExecutionHandler `.

Comment: There is one drawback though. In my use-case, if a task gets rejected (it happens with a small number of **queueSize**, there is not exception thrown, so there is no warning or error in the logs). How does a client know that their task got rejected?

Comment: Updated my answer so you could handle rejected threads.. Please note that when you have heave calculation the `threadPoolSize` must be max  = available processors or the cpu will randomly start processing part of thread1 .. stop it ... start with thread 5 ... stop it then back to thread 1 and continue execution ... (this scenario if 4 processors) same applied for less or more available processors in cpu. in the other hand, if your thread calling DB or external API's there is no issue with creating 100 in parallel al  let executionService handle how they run

Answer (score 1):

Thanks [Hussein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13493023/hussein-akar) and [also this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299784/using-threadpoolexecutor-and-discardpolicy/35691415#35691415) and [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).
It got it this way.

You can [check full sources](https://github.com/yan-khonski-it/back-pressure-example).

```
    private final ExecutorService executorService = initializeThreadPoolWithRejection();

    private ExecutorService initializeThreadPoolWithRejection() {
        final RejectedExecutionHandler handler = new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy();

        return new ThreadPoolExecutor(WORKERS_NUMBER, MAX_WORKERS_NUMBER,
                0L, TimeUnit.MINUTES,
                new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(10 /*queueSize*/),
                handler);
    }
```

Note, I use `ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy();` because it fails by default with `ExecutionException` exception.

**CalculationBroker**

```
    public CompletableFuture<CalculationResult> submit(final CalculationTask calculationTask) 
    {
        final CalculationResult calculationResultCached = calculationCache.get(calculationTask.getName());
        if (calculationResultCached != null) {
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(calculationResultCached);
        }

        LOGGER.info("Calculation submitted: {}.", calculationTask.getName());

        try {
            final CompletableFuture<CalculationResult> calculated = CompletableFuture
                    .supplyAsync(calculationTask::calculate, executorService);
            calculated.thenAccept(this::updateCache);
            return calculated;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to submit a task.");
            return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(e);
        }
    }
```

### Usage example in `Main`:

```
    private static void completeFuture(final CompletableFuture<CalculationResult> future) {
        final CalculationResult calculationResult;
        try {
            calculationResult = future.get();
            System.out.println("Task is finished: " + calculationResult);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Task was interrupted. " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            System.out.println("Task failed.");
        }
    }
```

It produces output:

```
2020-05-23 16:44:09 [main] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationBroker – Calculation submitted: CalculationTask_15.
2020-05-23 16:44:09 [main] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationBroker – Calculation submitted: CalculationTask_16.
2020-05-23 16:44:09 [main] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationBroker – Calculation submitted: CalculationTask_17.
2020-05-23 16:44:09 [main] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationBroker – Calculation submitted: CalculationTask_20.
Failed to submit a task.
2020-05-23 16:44:09 [main] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationBroker – Calculation submitted: CalculationTask_21.
Failed to submit a task.
2020-05-23 16:44:09 [main] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationBroker – Calculation submitted: CalculationTask_22.
Failed to submit a task.
2020-05-23 16:44:11 [pool-1-thread-8] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationTask – Calculation finished: CalculationResult{taskName='CalculationTask_17', text='This is result: 1096770940', number=1096770940, durationMs=1246}
2020-05-23 16:44:11 [pool-1-thread-4] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationTask – Calculation finished: CalculationResult{taskName='CalculationTask_3', text='This is result: 2103177010', number=2103177010, durationMs=1814}
2020-05-23 16:44:12 [pool-1-thread-6] INFO  c.y.t.backperssure.CalculationTask – Calculation finished: CalculationResult{taskName='CalculationTask_15', text='This is result: 961885863', number=961885863, durationMs=2632}
2
Task is finished: CalculationResult{taskName='CalculationTask_0', text='This is result: 79356259', number=79356259, durationMs=3875}
Task is finished: CalculationResult{taskName='CalculationTask_1', text='This is result: 532289460', number=532289460, durationMs=3725}
Task is finished: CalculationResult{taskName='CalculationTask_2', text='This is result: 1579151336', number=1579151336, durationMs=3684}
Task failed.
Task failed.
Task failed.
```

## Note, it works only in Java 9+.

`CompletableFuture.failedFuture(e);` does not work in Java 8.